# $N$ lines on a plane, proof of Area

Tags: calculus, induction

Say we have $n$ number of lines on a plane, none of which are parallel and there is never more than two of them intersecting each other at the same point. Lines divide the plane into $A_n$ different areas. The objective is to prove that $A_n=A_{n-1} + n$ and with induction that $A_n=(n^2+n+2)/2$. I have a minimal idea of how to approach this problem. I tried approximating how many different areas a number of intersecting lines would create but it did not seem to help very much. Any ideas? And what is meant by dividing the plane into areas by these lines?

Now that I think about this, it would seem that $A_n$ just increases by adding $n$ number of lines to the previous area. Does this mean that there is always one extra line that yields a new area?

I may be wrong, but in my opinion, the question in the textbook is either obvious and does not require overthinking or is simply poorly stated? The most important aspect is the proof by induction, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the first 4 regions between the red lines in arabic numbers, the 3 new ones due to the black line have roman numerals.[image]

Comment: Thank you, this visualization helped a lot. What would the inductive proof look like then?

Comment: maybe ad a fourth and fifth  line and think  of four like n, its the same argument, how many lines do you cross, that gives you  how many new regions.

Comment: Note that the very same induction argument can be generalized in any dimension. If $A_{n, d}$ is the number of regions created by $n$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^d$, an hyperplane creates as many new regions as the intersection of the other hyperplanes create $(d-1)$-dimensional regions on the new hyperplane. So we have $A_{n,d} = A_{n-1,d} + A_{n-1, d-1}$. This makes a nice table, initialized by $A_{n,0} = 1$ (dimension $0$ space cannot be cut) and $A(0,d) = 1$ (a non-cut space has 1 region).

Answer (score 1):

Start with two lines : easy 4 regions, than add a third how many new ones? and a fourth?  then imagine n lines how many new ones appear with one more ? how many lines will it cross, thats the induction.

Comment: I could see how two intersecting lines would make 4 regions. The third line would just add one more region (on the other side). I think I am confusing simple integral calculus where the area is calculated as one region under the curves(in this case lines). But let's say for three lines on a plane...two intersecting each other, and one next to them arbitrarily placed then, in that case, $A_3=A_2 +3$, and since $A_2$ area yields 4, in that case, the area of three lines is marked by $7$ regions. This does not make sense to me, I thought that one line would just yield $1$ or 2 regions.

Comment: @Aristarchus_: Start tracing the new line from infinity. Each time the new line reaches an existing line, you divide an existing region into two—possibly open-ended, possibly closed, but in any event you split the region into two. At the end, therefore, you add as many regions as there were existing lines. ¶ I think it would help you to draw these out.

Comment: @BrianTung; Yes, but as you say I thought the new line splits the region into two, in which case we would get 6 regions for $A_3$ as I mentioned above, and not 7. In what way am I mistaken?

Comment: @Aristarchus_: You get one new region per line—existing plus one (my previous comment had an off-by-one error). So, for example, $A_2 = 4$. So the new line—call it $\ell_3$—crosses the two existing lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$. It therefore crosses three existing areas: before $\ell_1$ (so to speak), between $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$, and after $\ell_2$. We therefore have $A_3 = A_2 + 3 = 7$. Then $A_4 = A_3 + 4 = 11$, etc. Sorry!

Comment: @BrianTung; But what are the three existing areas, wasn't it just $4$ for $A_2$ and adding one new region with a new line. I don't understand the 2 additional areas, and the "existing areas" that you are referring to...